# Disabling right drawer only on specific fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, drawerlayout

I have `Activity` with `DrawerLayout` (which contains left and right drawer). I was wondering if I could disable right drawer from specific fragments.

I've read about `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)`, but it would lock whole drawer closed, and I still need the left drawer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(int lockMode)` locks all the drawers, but to lock a specific drawer you can use one of the following:

- [`DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(int lockMode, int edgeGravity)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setdrawerlockmode_2)
- [`DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(int lockMode, View drawerView)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setdrawerlockmode)