# Disable swipe gesture (navigation drawer) from specific fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I would like to disable the swipe gesture that opens the navigation drawer but only from an specific fragment, I mean I don't want to disable it from whole application.

I have read many questions and it seems one of them works, but I probably dont understand exactly what I have to do: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858420/disabling-right-drawer-only-on-specific-fragment/25380493?noredirect=1#comment39582672_25380493)

I have tried this:

**MainActivity, onCreate:**

```
mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, R.layout.fragment_my_favourite);
```

R.layout.fragment_my_favourite: fragment where I want to disable the drawer.

I would appreciate any hint. Thank you a lot

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried this:

MainActivity:

```
private ViewDragHelper draggerObj;
private Field mDragger;
private Field mEdgeSize;
private int edge;
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;

public void closeDrag()
{       
    try 
    {
       mDragger = mDrawer.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLeftDragger");
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mDragger.setAccessible(true);

    try 
    {
        draggerObj = (ViewDragHelper) mDragger.get(mDrawer);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        mEdgeSize = draggerObj.getClass().getDeclaredField("mEdgeSize");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mEdgeSize.setAccessible(true);

    try 
    {
      edge = mEdgeSize.getInt(draggerObj);
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        mEdgeSize.setInt(draggerObj, edge * 0);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And after I call this method from my fragment:

onCreate:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity instanceof MainActivity){
        ((MainActivity) activity).closeDrag();
    }
```

Comment: you want your drawer to disable swipe only with finger ? right

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but only in an specifi fragment.

Comment: Can you plz post updated part & what exactly your code is ?

Comment: your MainActivity is extending ActionBarActivity ? right

Comment: Yes it is extending ActinBarActivity. The drawer is working, disabling the gesture to open the drawer is what is not working.

Comment: Ok I have created a new project to try this and it's working perfectly. I must check carefully my code. Thak you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code & it works for me.

```
public void closeDrag()
    {
        try 
        {
            mDragger = drawerLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLeftDragger");
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mDragger.setAccessible(true);

        try 
        {
            draggerObj = (ViewDragHelper) mDragger.get(drawerLayout);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try 
        {
            mEdgeSize = draggerObj.getClass().getDeclaredField("mEdgeSize");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mEdgeSize.setAccessible(true);

        try 
        {
            edge = mEdgeSize.getInt(draggerObj);
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try 
        {
            mEdgeSize.setInt(draggerObj, edge * 0);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note: `it will allow to open/close drawer from Actionbar button but will disable finger swipe.`

Comment: try this & if it helps you plz accept as an answer.

Comment: I get java.lang.NullPointerException at the first Try. I have initialized the variable as null (mDragger, mEdgeSize...). Is this maybe the problem?

Comment: i make it global--> Field mDragger, mEdgeSize; & not null.

Comment: I am still getting null pointer exception. I have created this method in MainActivity and I create a MainActivity object at the fragment class. After i do this >>
  if (main instanceof MainActivity){
   main.closeDrag();
  }

Comment: Actually I have used it in a Activity (onCreate) not in fragment, & make that activity as a base class & extend other activities with it.

Comment: & Iam getting no exceptions

Comment: int edge is also not null & global variable; same as ViewDragHelper draggerObj;

Comment: I have changed part of my code and I am not getting nullpointerexception anymore but it is not working for me. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 5):

```
//Blocked swipe navigation drawer
mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely useful. Please consider adding some context to your answer.

Comment: Your answer has easy method but it would be good if you also add the gravity or from where your drawer will get open like Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.RIGHT and it also add more stability. Check Here the official guide
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int, int)